# Binding issue when generate files with erb in ruby

Tags: ruby, erb

How can i pass the template name as a string when creating the "A" object. If I do that with the following code it will be written the name of the template instead of it's representation.

```
template1 = "Today is <%= @weekday %>."
template2 = "Tomorow is <%= @weekday %>."
template3 = "Yesterday was <%= @weekday %>."

class A
  include ERB::Util

  def initialize template, day
    @template = template
    @weekday = day
  end

  def render()
    ERB.new(@template).result
    #ERB.new(@template).result(binding)
  end

  def save(file)
    File.open(file, "w+") do |f|
      f.write(render)
    end
  end
end

day = Time.now.strftime('%A')

#name of template from outside source as a string
template_to_use = 'template3'

list = A.new template_to_use, day
list.save 'list.txt'
```

If i change the expression to `template_to_use = template3` (removing the quotes) the code works fine and the file is generated correctly accordingly to the template, but the problem here is I will receive this value from a yml definition, and this value will come as a string.

So I need in some way to use this string as a method name.
But I don't know how can I do It.
Any help, or a better approach for this kind of problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are really looking for is a hash:

```
templates = {
  'template1' => "Today is <%= @weekday %>.",
  'template2' => "Tomorow is <%= @weekday %>.",
  'template3' => "Yesterday was <%= @weekday %>."
}

# your other stuff here...

template_to_use = templates['template3']  #=> "Yesterday was <%= @weekday %>."
```

Comment: Ok I find a solution to my initial problem. I can solve the problem using the eval. Anyway Wally Altam although it was not the solution that I was looking for thank you anyway for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for the problem, with a litle change in template definition

```
def template3
    %{ "Today is <%= @weekday %>." }
end
```

and with use of eval

```
def initialize template, day
  @template = eval(template)
  #Other code
end
```

Obs: The code isn't the prettiest one, but it wasn't the main issue here.